# Initialize a linked list using ints in C

Tags: c, linked-list, int

I need to initialize a linked list using ints given from the main.c.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) 
{
     int b = 128;
     int M = b * 11;  // so we have space for 11 items

     char buf [1024];
     memset (buf, 1, 1024);     // set each byte to 1

     char * msg = "a sample message";

     Init (M,b); // initialize
```

I know what I have isn't correct, but it's the best I could come up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linked_list.h"

struct node
{
     int value;
     struct node *next;
};

struct node* head;
struct node* tail;

void    Init (int M, int b)
{
     head = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *head);
     tail = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof *tail);
     head->next = tail;
     tail->next = tail;
}
```

I just cannot see how to initialize the linked list using the ints. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your list is described by a pointer to its head element.

Now you want to initialise the list so that it is usable. The default state is an empty list, i.e. one that does not have any nodes. So what you *don't* do is to allocate memory. Just do this:

```
struct node *head = NULL;
```

You have a `NULL` head, which means that you don't have any elements. When you add nodes, you create them with `malloc` and assign them via this pointer. If the `head` is `NULL`, it must be updated to point to the first node, whose `next` member must be `NULL`.

Remember: Most pointers just point to existing data. There's no need to allocate memory to such pointers. And make sure to always initialise pointers properly; they should either point to valid memory or be `NULL` to mean "not pointing to anything".

Comment: I understand, but the main.c was given to us and the point of this was to learn how to use pointers and linked lists along with the allocated memory

Comment: I see. In that case a have no idea what the function is supposed to do. What is the char buffer for? And why do you have to specify the number of items beforehand.

Comment: We are creating a high performance linked list that will avoid interacting with the memory manager on a per-operation basis

Comment: Okay, how are we supposed to know that, by reading your mind? And why ist your first idea to call `malloc` then, which is a call to the memory manager. It is of course possible to write a linked list with pre-allocated items. I guess that is what the char buffer is for, but wouldn't it be better to create a pool of nodes? Anyway, as is, the question cannot be answered. I would advise to look into regular linked lists that use `malloc` first before you embark on rolling your own memory pool.